# embeding graphic bars in HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, highcharts

Is there a way to embed a graphical bars in an HTML bar chart?
Another way to look at it : is there is a way to somehow correlate textual rows with a barcart?
I'm prototype'ing with highcharts which meets many of the the requirements, but one requirement is to show several fields of textual data next to the bars in the barchart and not be limited to just a single label for each bar in the bar chart.

Comment: What is the difference between many labels (as you want), and one label with long text with line breaks?

Comment: It would be nice to be able to sort by columns for example and have links on each field in the columns. Here is an example I tracked down, though I wish the example was on jsfiddle: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/HTMLHorizontalBarChart.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Did you saw jqPlot? [Here](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php), in the second example you can see something that looks like your link, I think.

Comment: I'm actually using Highcharts which is richer than jqPlot and I don't see a way to do it in Highcharts. I'm tempted to try and use http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/